# how to evaluate rendering performance of d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using d3 for 3rd party visualization solution. And I'm wondering is there anyway to evaluate the rendering performance of d3? I'm rending about 500 gauges at the same time. And it's rendering within 100ms. But is there any way to use the numbers to evaluate this performance?

Comment: have you tried profiling in dev tools?

Comment: @atmd I'm trying chrome profiling tool. And I'm using vs2013 for the development. Can I use any dev tools in vs2013?

Comment: It sounds to me like you're already evaluating the performance by measuring how long it takes.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff  Yes, I'm using the chrome timeline to do this. I'm wondering if there're other general and precise ways to do the performance evaluation as we still need the support in ie, safari or firefox.

Comment: I guess that would depend on the browser. You could use a framework like [selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/).

Comment: @LarsKotthoff This helps, Thanks!